# Measures disappear after add parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

I have dataset MDX query like this:

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { 
[Measures].[InventarioDirectoInventario_Inventario],
 [Measures].[InventarioDirectoInventario_InventarioAcumulado], 
[Measures].[InventarioDirectoVentas_VentaAcumulada],
 [Measures].[InventarioDirectoVentas_Ventas] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { (
[Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].[Anio].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_Tiempo_].[NombreMesAbreviado].[NombreMesAbreviado].ALLMEMBERS
 * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdGrupo].[IdGrupo].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[NombreGrupo].[NombreGrupo].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdDivision].[IdDivision].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[NombreDivision].[NombreDivision].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdPlanta].[IdPlanta].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[Planta].[Planta].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_ConceptosInventario_].[keyClave].[keyClave].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_ConceptosInventario_].[sNombreConcepto].[sNombreConcepto].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [BSC] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

It runs correctly and it returns all fields, problem start when I want to add parameters  `Anio` and `Mes` like this:

```
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimTiempoMes, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimTiempoAnio, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [BSC])) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

For some reason

`[Measures].[InventarioDirectoVentas_VentaAcumulada]`

and

```
[Measures].[InventarioDirectoVentas_Ventas]
```

Disappear from my return fields, and I don't have any idea why. Something particular of this fields is that them can return null but before parameters added it returned without problems, now with filters of `Mes` and `Anio` it just don't return field, they disappear. Can someone knows what is wrong there? Regards

Comment: you need to really simplify the script - then start adding in complexity until things start misbehaving

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Non Empty before a column set:

```
SELECT { 
[Measures].[InventarioDirectoInventario_Inventario],
 [Measures].[InventarioDirectoInventario_InventarioAcumulado], 
[Measures].[InventarioDirectoVentas_VentaAcumulada],
 [Measures].[InventarioDirectoVentas_Ventas] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { (
[Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].[Anio].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_Tiempo_].[NombreMesAbreviado].[NombreMesAbreviado].ALLMEMBERS
 * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdGrupo].[IdGrupo].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[NombreGrupo].[NombreGrupo].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdDivision].[IdDivision].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[NombreDivision].[NombreDivision].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdPlanta].[IdPlanta].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[Planta].[Planta].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_ConceptosInventario_].[keyClave].[keyClave].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_ConceptosInventario_].[sNombreConcepto].[sNombreConcepto].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [BSC] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```